# What is the purpose of OAuth User Token and OAuth User Secret I get from LinkedId when creating an application

Tags: oauth, linkedin-api

When creating a new application in LinkedIn, I get 4 separate codes:

1. API Key
2. Secret Key
3. **OAuth User Token**
4. **OAuth User Secret**

I'm using the first two in the OAuth flow. What is the purpose of the **last two**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading some more, I figured it's my own user's token and secret. The reason they are provided is to simplify the initial calls to LinkedIn API.

Comment: Can you post where you read this?  I put what I found in another answer, but I'd love it if you found something I missed.

Comment: Having both `OAuth User Token` and `OAuth User Secret` how to get user data?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to documentation I found is [this forum post](http://developer.linkedin.com/comment/18961#comment-18961) from a LinkedIn employee.  However, this post does not clarify everything, such as:  Will this token ever expire?  Does this token have all member permissions?

Based on a little experimentation, I suspect the answers are no and yes.  But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically use for the API testing purpose before you move forward to implement your application, you make sure the linkedin API working fine.

For more you can see this link https://github.com/saranpal/linkedin-api-quick-start-php, here is simple example for fetching company information.

Cheers!